# SQL Inner Join Two Tables supplying both sets of data

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to join two tables, twice:

- `Fixtures` table (Fixture ID, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID)
- `Team` table (TeamID, TeamName)

With the following query:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Test1]
AS 
    SELECT 
        XMLFixture.ID AS ID, 
        HomeTeam.Name AS HomeTeam, AwayTeam.Name as AwayTeam
    FROM 
        [XMLSoccer-Fixture] XMLFixture
    INNER JOIN 
        [XMLSoccer-Team] HomeTeam ON HomeTeam.ID = XMLFixture.HomeTeamID
    INNER JOIN 
        [XMLSoccer-Team] AwayTeam ON AwayTeam.ID = XMLFixture.AwayTeamID
```

The problem I'm having is that for every `HomeTeam`, it's also returning the entire list of away teams. So if I have 1,000 Teams. It's returning 1,000 records for HomeTeam with every single Team. I think I need to tweak my join somehow, but not too sure how,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Got some sample data and sample results?

Comment: Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33dabc/1 which shows what you explained, but without any duplication problems (which is why @dfundako and upvoters are asking for sample data and desired results).

Comment: @JNevill - Fixed, I had my conditions the wrong way round...

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had my TeamID the wrong way round, this works fine:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Test1]
AS 
SELECT 
    XMLFixture.ID AS ID, 
    HomeTeam.Name AS HomeTeam, AwayTeam.Name as AwayTeam
FROM 
    [XMLSoccer-Fixture] XMLFixture
INNER JOIN 
    [XMLSoccer-Team] HomeTeam ON XMLFixture.HomeTeamID = HomeTeam.ID
INNER JOIN 
    [XMLSoccer-Team] AwayTeam ON XMLFixture.AwayTeamID = AwayTeam.ID
```

Comment: where you place the ID field on the left or the right of the equals doesnt make any difference in SQL